# How to get desired text using css selector in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

On hotels.com I want to get location text("Tbilisi" in the first example)

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url="https://www.hotels.com/Hotel-Search?adults=2&d1=2022-07-01&d2=2022-07-02&destination=Georgia&endDate=2022-07-02&latLong=42.211058611965235%2C43.30777377386527&regionId=11403&rooms=1&semdtl=&sort=RECOMMENDED&startDate=2022-07-01&theme=&useRewards=false&userIntent="

soup=bs(requests.get(url).content,"html.parser")

locations=soup.select("section.results li div div div:nth-child(2) div div")
for location in locations:
    print(location.text)
```

This code returns every text(except hotel name). How to modify code to get only the desired text?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, select upto li tag as list for iterating then select the desired data using `select_one()`

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url="https://www.hotels.com/Hotel-Search?adults=2&d1=2022-07-01&d2=2022-07-02&destination=Georgia&endDate=2022-07-02&latLong=42.211058611965235%2C43.30777377386527&regionId=11403&rooms=1&semdtl=&sort=RECOMMENDED&startDate=2022-07-01&theme=&useRewards=false&userIntent="

soup=bs(requests.get(url).content,"html.parser")

locations=soup.select("section.results > ol > li")
for location in locations:
    loc=location.select_one('div[data-test-id="content-hotel-neighborhood"]')
    loc=loc.text if loc else None
    print(loc)
```

**Output:**

```
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
None   
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
None   
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
Kutaisi
None
Tbilisi
Tbilisi
```